# What do these warnings on Python pdfminer3k mean?

Tags: python, pdfminer

What do these warnings on Python pdfminer3k mean?

> WARNING:pdfminer.layout:Too many boxes (104) to group, skipping.
>   WARNING:pdfminer.layout:Too many boxes (122) to group, skipping.

Comment: there are too many boxes to group, so it is skipping those boxes

Comment: what does these boxes means?

Answer (score 1):

The [source](https://github.com/jaepil/pdfminer3k/blob/master/pdfminer/layout.py#L624) for the function [**`group_textboxes`**](https://github.com/jaepil/pdfminer3k/blob/master/pdfminer/layout.py#L597) has the following comment:

```
# Grouping this many boxes would take too long and it doesn't make much sense to do so
# considering the type of grouping (nesting 2-sized subgroups) that is done here.
```

Comment: I just used this community,but I was moved by the good people in the community.